# OpenSSL without password

Tags: openssl, passwords, certificate

How can I configure openssl to make "challengePassword" optional, not required.

I tried adding it to the policy as

```
challengePassword = optional
```

and I have also tried removing or setting the following lines to `... = 0`

```
challengePassword_min       = 4
challengePassword_max       = 20
```

To clarify, I am not looking to pass a password on command line or to have one automatically added. I also know how to remove a password after it has been added, but for the life of me, I can not recall what I did in an older config file to disable the requirement during generation.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you're not looking for password less authentication with ssh keys? i.e. run an agent to keep the key in memory?

Comment: @VincentDeSmet - no.  The specific purpose is for creating certificates that will be signed by my own CA and Intermediate -- different than "self-signed".